# Cursor with Table type not working

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is my cursor

Passing Table Type to cursor to update table column.

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM @AutoDataType 
OPEN cur    
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Customer_Id,@First_Name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN           
  UPDATE [dbo].[ABC] SET [Customer_Id] =@Customer_Id            
  WHERE LOWER([PH_FirstName])=LOWER(@First_Name)                    
  FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Customer_Id,@First_Name
END
CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
```

When I tried to execute this cursor from query window as below it works fine

```
Declare @AutoDataType As [dbo].[Auto_DataType]
Insert Into @AutoDataType(Customer_Id,First_Name) Values('11111','JOHN');
Exec sp_TEST @AutoDataType
```

But through C# code its not working, and no error also.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my Table Type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Auto_DataType] AS TABLE([Customer_Id] [varchar](50) NULL,
                                           [First_Name] [varchar](50) NULL)
```

Here is my Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TEST](@AutoDataType As [dbo].[Auto_DataType] Readonly)
AS
Begin
DECLARE @Row_Id Int;
DECLARE @Customer_Id Varchar(50);
DECLARE @First_Name Varchar(50);
DECLARE @Last_Name Varchar(50);
DECLARE @DOB Varchar(50);
DECLARE @License_Number Varchar(50);
DECLARE @TransId VARCHAR(50);   
DECLARE @TimeStamp DATETIME;    
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM @AutoDataType 
OPEN cur    
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Customer_Id,@First_Name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN           
        UPDATE [dbo].[ABC] SET [Customer_Id]  =@Customer_Id            
        WHERE LOWER([PH_FirstName])=LOWER(@First_Name)   
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Customer_Id,@First_Name
    END
CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur  
End
```

Comment: please add to your question all the elements. i suppose the cursor is part of a stored procedure because you call it with `Exec sp_TEST @AutoDataType`; what's inside that stored procedure? what's the definition of that custom data type?

Comment: this looks like sql-server, not mysql

Comment: Please suggest me how to loop through Table type and update the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a cursor here at all. This should be a single update statement.

```
UPDATE a SET [Customer_Id] = adt.Customer_Id            
FROM @AutoDataType adt
JOIN [dbo].[ABC] a on a.PH_FirstName = adt.First_Name
WHERE LOWER(a.[PH_FirstName]) = LOWER(adt.First_Name)
```

Please note that unless you have a case sensitive collation the where predicate here is pointless. Just like in your code it will update the row even if they are not the same case. I would recommend just removing the where clause.